# How to make Firefox use native notification (notify-osd)?

Tags: firefox, notification, notify-osd

I've seen this:

[image: Notification image]

As you can see Firefox is using the Ubuntu notification to notify the user.

How to do that?

I just want to get notifications for anything in general: for example, if a download is completed...

Comment: You don't already get these notifications? Do you get notifications for anything?

Comment: At least for download is finished YES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE: 08-01-2020**

As the [GNotifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnotifier/) extension is dead, you can use the **Firefox Gnome Download Notifications**.
Add the extension from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-download-notifications/).

[image]

---

Ok found it:

[GNotifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnotifier/) is a Firefox extension that makes the browser use native notifications on the Linux desktop. The extension currently supports GNOME (Shell), Unity, KDE and Xfce.

Besides regular notifications, like the one displayed when a file is downloaded, the extension also supports the standard webkitNotification API (for instance, receiving notifications on new emails in Gmail)

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/make-firefox-use-native-notifications.html)

Comment: While this does re-enable download notifications, they are not native on Firefox anymore.

Answer (score 11):

Install the GNotifier addon to get firefox notifications to integrate with the current desktop you are using, either unity, gnome-shell, kde or xfce.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnotifier/

Comment: Will GNotifier be updated for Firefox Quantum (Firefox 57)?

Comment: @adeora doesn't look like it. https://github.com/mkiol/GNotifier/issues/197

Answer (score 1):

The **GNotifier** extension is dead. It was active in March 2016 and provided by Mozilla the manufacturer of Firefox as this article describes:

- [Make Firefox Use Native Linux Notifications in Unity, XFCE And GNOME Shell](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/g-notifier-firefox-ubuntu-notification-bubbles)

The best course of action would be to put a [wish list request](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/wishlist-faq#make-wish) to Mozilla.