# Firefox notifications overlaps Unity task bar

Tags: unity, firefox, gui, notification

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and with Firefox 54, browser notifications (apparently via `libnotify`) look like this:

[image]

Reproduced with [this test site](https://gauntface.github.io/simple-push-demo/).

You can see how the notification all but covers the important part of the top bar. This has disturbed me often enough to make me post this, so I'd like to either make Firefox use the *real* native, i.e. Unity, notifications (like seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/411927/69674)), or reposition the ones I got to not cover the bar.

How can I do either?

Comment: I think it's not related to Ubuntu, since these notifications are managed strictly by Firefox. Look at this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/push-notifications-firefox

Comment: @Redbob That page seems to be dealing with the server<->browser pathway.

Comment: So did you try the GNotifier add-on that you linked to?

Comment: @DKBose No, since it's apparently a Thunderbird-only addon.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like Google Chrome has these notifications on by default. Of course one has the choice to allow or block each site. In the case of Kubuntu 16.04, the notifications appear in the lower right corner of the screen, the same place as other system notifications are placed. I used the github one.

Comment: @DKBose Is my question not clear? I *want* the notifications, I just don't them *there*.

Comment: Your question *is* clear. I wanted to see if Kubuntu allowed me to change the location where notifications appear. But it doesn't.